# Read and write text file with escape sequences

Tags: java

Learning Java by coding...

Read and write text file to insert tabs to further be imported into Mnemosyne

I got a text file written by hand by myself like this:

First line of text\tansewer

Second line of text\tanswer

Third line of text\tansewer

However when I try to print it or write it to a file I don't get the tab I need.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "jeg.txt";
    String line = null;
    String[] mylines = new String[20];
    int i = 0;

    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            mylines[i++] = line;

        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you inserting tab characters? I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: You should show the code that creates the file.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, what are you trying to do? your code just read a file and fill an array of size 20 (this could lead to an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` easily)

Comment: I create the text file myself (add \t manually). This also means that I know the exact size.

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing is reading the information into a variable. Once you have the information, you have to output it somewhere for it to show up.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "jeg.txt";
    String line = null;
    String[] mylines = new String[20];
    int i = 0;

try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        mylines[i++] = line;

    }
    bufferedReader.close();
}
for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
   System.out.println(mylines[j]);
}
```

This will output your lines to the system line. You can use the same concept in a tab or anywhere else.

Comment: for (String itm : mylines) {
            System.out.println(itm);
        } I also got this line but it still prints \t and not the tab

Comment: If you open note pad and you see the \t, you will also see it in the read line. Because it will automatically convert it to \\t when it is read from a file. If you are writing the output to, perhaps we should look at that to see why it is outputting a \t